How to add labels to a graphics grid?
I have a grid of contour plots that looks like

is there any way to add one label as "longitude" and one as "latitude" to the bottom and left sides, respectively?
simple code:
plot1 = MatrixPlot[RandomReal[{-1000, 1000}, {100, 100}], 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"];

plot2 = MatrixPlot[RandomReal[{-1000, 10}, {100, 100}], 
  ColorFunction -> "Pastel"];

Grid[{{plot1, plot2, plot1, plot2}, {plot1, plot2, plot1, 
   plot2}, {plot1, plot2, plot1, plot2}, {plot1, plot2, plot1, 
   plot2}}]


Labeled[Grid[{...}], {"longitude", "latitude"}, {Bottom, Left}]

The better way using Labeled has been indicated by Bob Hanlon in the comments.
Using Grid:
x0 = {{plot1, plot2, plot1, plot2}, {plot1, plot2, plot1, 
   plot2}, {plot1, plot2, plot1, plot2}, {plot1, plot2, plot1, plot2}};

Grid[{
  {Rotate[Style["Latitude", Bold, 24], \[Pi]/2], Grid@x0}
  , {SpanFromLeft, Style["Longitude", Bold, 24]}
  }, Frame -> All]




You can remove the Frame command for an alternate look. It is indispensable while one is struggling with the Span* entries.

I think that the easiest way is using the excellent PlotGrid resource function:
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][
  {{plot1, plot2, plot1, plot2},
   {plot1, plot2, plot1, plot2},
   {plot1, plot2, plot1, plot2},
   {plot1, plot2, plot1, plot2}},
  FrameLabel -> {"longitude", "latitude", "", ""}, 
  ImageSize  -> Large]



To make include the inner FrameTicks and PlotLabels: ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][Table[Plot[x^n + m, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> {n, m}, Frame -> True], {n, 3}, {m, 3}], Spacings -> 40, FrameLabel -> {"Label A", "Label B"}]. And if you only want the PlotLabels: ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][Table[Plot[x^n+m,{x,0,1},PlotLabel->{n,m},Frame->True],{n,3},{m,3}],Spacings->{None,20},FrameLabel->{"Label A","Label B"},"ShowFrameLabels"->Automatic]
